# Can't find a fragment with a tag

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some trouble to find a fragment by a Tag:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged);

        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.nav_bar);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        Fragment profilFragment = new ProfilFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, profilFragment,"profil_frag");
        fragTransaction.addToBackStack("profil_frag").commit();

        Fragment testTag = (ProfilFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("profil_frag");
        Toast.makeText(Logged.this, "test fragtag = " + testTag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    }
```

The fragment is created and displayed without problem but the Toast check print "test fragtag = **null**".
It's surely a mistake from me but I don't understand why.

Comment: testTag returns a fragment not an actual text or string

Comment: Also, You're using `profil_frag` when replacing and `profil_tag` in `findFragmentByTag()`

Comment: So should I add instead of replacing ? But it's still null, so he don't found any fragment with this tag, no ?

Comment: `fragTransaction.commit()` is not immediate, [it is scheduled](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#commit()). Try replacing it by `fragTransaction.commitNow()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your toast and i thin that testTag returns a fragment instead of a string , You can the following instead to check for the tag

```
Fragment testTag =(Profilfragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("profil_frag");
```

```
 Toast.makeText(Logged.this, "test fragtag = " + testTag.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
```

Comment: when I try to run this Toast the app crash, I think it's because testTag is null.

Comment: `2020-07-15 15:30:18.466 12935-12935/com.example.handycatch D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-07-15 15:30:18.467 12935-12935/com.example.handycatch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.handycatch, PID: 12935
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.handycatch/com.example.handycatch.Logged}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getTag()' on a null object reference
       t

Comment: i editted my code can you check it , type cast your fragment to your profilefragment

Comment: I editted my code as you advised it to me and the problem still the same

Answer (score 0):

You didn't commit the transaction:

```
fragTransaction.commit()
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add put the commit in the question, I edited it.

Comment: @RoiKrush You have to commit it before the Toast check. Commit executes the transaction and only after that the fragment can be found.

Comment: Ok thx tryed that way but it's still nul. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `.addToBackStack("profil_frag")`

Also when you doing

```
Fragment testTag =
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("profil_frag");
```

cast it to `ProfilFragment`